# jQuery : How do I put clicked element in input box?

Tags: php, jquery, click

I'm trying to get a list going.

I have an empty input box in which I want to store a list: Mary, Kate, Brock

Now I have a select list with those three names in it. I want to know how can I transfer the name clicked from the select list into the input box. If I click a second name, add a comma to separate the one from the previous one.

Appreciate your help. I have no idea to where/how to even start this :(

Comment: This question was asked before, but I cannot find it. Is the select box a multiple select box, meaning do you want to have the currently selected in the text field or do you want to add the names to the text field based on the order they have been selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

<select name="names" id="names">
    <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
    <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
    <option value="Brock">Brock</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#names").change(function() {
        name = $(this).val();
        current = $("#name").val();
        if (!$("#name").val()) {
            $("#name").val(name);
        } else {
            if (current.indexOf(name) == -1) {
                $("#name").val(current + ', ' + name);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Adds new name to end of list, only adds a comma when there is more than one name and duplicates are now allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the value from an input element with `$('#the_id').val();`, and you can manipulate the value of an input element in the same way: `$('#the_id').val('new value');`. Combine that with the `.click` handler and you should be all set:

```
$('#selector').click(function(){
  var $names = $('#names')
  $names.val($names.val() + ', ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `change` event:

```
$('#listbox').change(function(){
   var selectedName = $('#listbox option[value='+$(this).val()+']').text();
   $('#input-for-insert').append(selectedName);
});
```

I think you make yourself comma separation)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

<select name="names" id="names">
    <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
    <option value="Kate">Kate</option>
    <option value="Brock">Brock</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // When the names selection changes
        $("#names").change(function()
        {
            // Get the new name from this selection list
            newName = $(this).val();

            // Get any names currently in the input box
            currentName = $("#name").val();

            // Change the value of the name box by adding the newName followed by a comma
            // followed by the current names
            $("#name").val(newName + ", " + currentName);
        });
    }
</script>
```